# Remove characters between top level html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In summary, I am looking for a bulletproof solution to remove \n's from between HTML tags to make well-formed HTML instead of the quirks-mode string I am receiving.

Longer explanation: I have a string that contains HTML. There are \n strings between some of the top-level tags that I need to remove, BUT I must not remove \n's from inside tag content.

Example:

```
<p class='A'>AA A AAA</p>\n   \n  \n <p class='B'>BB BB \n BB\nBBB BB</p>
```

The \n's between the paras need to go, but the \n's in the para with class=B must stay. This is a trumped up example - in the real world there are no predefined classes etc, I just get para tags with unpredictable content.

What did I try:

- Simple string replacement is out because, of course, it hits the \n's in the second para element which must be retained.
- I have looked for a regexp solution but can't grok how to make them work selectively as is required. Even though regex is clever I think it still sees a 'stream' rather than a 'structure'
- I tried loading the HTML into a div and pulling back that div's HTML hoping that it would 'clean up' the intertag \n's but not so.

Here is my current solution using jquery to do the clean up. This only works for me becuse I know that there is no text that I want to keep inbetween the top level tags. Also it cannot be made recursive to clean the grandchildren or lower because any text wold be lost.

```js
var dIn =  $('#in');   // div to act as container to load subject html
var dOut = $('#out');  // div to act as container for cleaing op
var sOut='';           // string to accumulate output

var sIn = "<p class='A'>AA A\n AAA</p>\n   \n  \n <p class='B'>BB BB \n BB\nBBB BB<span>CC\nC</p>";
$('#t1').val(sIn);  // display starting string

dIn.html(sIn);  // load input string into a div element

dIn.children().each(function(){ // walk the children of the container
  dOut.append($(this));         // append each child of input container to output container
  sOut = sOut + dOut.html();     // and yank the output containers html to give the tag-only content
  dOut.html('');                // last clear the output container for the next pass 
})

// show the results
$('#t2').val(sOut);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="in"></div>


<div id="out"></div>

<div id="info">
  <textarea id='t1' rows='10' cols='40'>
  </textarea>
  <textarea id='t2' rows='10' cols='40'> 
  </textarea>
  
</div>
```

Note: in case the comment is lost, [this post explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654) why regex will not work. Props to [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene).

Comment: Regex and HTML are not good friends, use [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: Are you talking about newlines or literal backslash-n sequences?

Comment: @melpomene this is javascript so the differentiation is kind of irrelevant? I see them in the string as backslash-n but JS sees that as a newline. However, in a more generic solution there could be other 'junk' chars that would de desirable to remove.

Comment: The difference is not irrelevant. One is single character (0x0A), the other is two very different characters (0x5C 0x6E). Which one is it?

Comment: You should consider using a server-side DOM manipulation library

Comment: @melpomene Fair point. They are \n characters. I believe the string I receive comes from some editing tool that sends \n in place of line breaks to avoid the confusion or line-break formats on different device OS's.

Comment: @rnirnber That is not in scope of my use-case, thanks - I just receive this string from a service that I cannot alter. Regardless of that though, I think the issue would be the same meaning the solution has to be structure-aware and cannot just process a string.

Comment: Nice to see the haters are out to play. It would be nice to get a reason for the down votes please.

Comment: A regex solution would be capturing text between tags using `<\/\w+>([^<>]+)<\w+(?:\s+[\w-]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))?)*\s*>` then remove newline characters off of it.

Comment: @revo But that would not descriminate between \n's in top-level tags I think.

Comment: Example? @VanquishedWombat

Comment: @revo - since you posted your answer with working regexp solution I will take back my concern that regexp can't discriminate. Nice one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions are tricky in dealing with HTML documents as elements can nest in each other makes you be aware of different things leading in complexity, leaving you in a terrible situation and providing a nasty buggy workaround that all to me means headache.

Use a parser instead. A DOM parser actually not a regex-based parser. Below DOM solution works on first level nodes that at this point differs from RegEx solution.

DOM solution:

```js
var html = `<p class='A'>AA A AAA</p>
   
  
 <p class='B' test required >BB BB 
 BB
BBB BB</p>`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
// Only immediate children of body
var query = doc.evaluate('//body/*/following-sibling::text()',
        doc,
        null,
        XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
        null
    );

for (let i = 0, length = query.snapshotLength; i < length; i++) {
    query.snapshotItem(i).textContent = query.snapshotItem(i).textContent.replace(/\n/g, "");
}

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

RegEx solution (not preferred - it looks for closing tags and opening tags which reside beside each other respectively):

```js
var html = `<p class='A'>AA A AAA</p>
   
  
 <p class='B' test required >BB BB
 BB
BBB BB</p>`

console.log(html.replace(/(<\/\w+>)([^<>]+)(<\w+(?:\s+[\w-]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))?)*\s*>)/g, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + $2.replace(/\n/g, '') + $3;
}));
```

Comment: the DOMParser looks interesting. I am unfamiliar with it but it looks good.

Comment: Just as a follow up, after 3+ months of operation the DPM parser approach suggested by @revo has been working well since installed to live.